# Does the arrival of vehicle on a specified point of a road follow a poisson process?

Tags: probability, distributions, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I am asking about a poisson with the same rate but different serving time, because a point in a road have a maximum capacity of letting a number of cars pass through it, but in the same time the speed of the vehicles is variable so if a car is slow it is going to take a longer serving time, while on the other hand if a car is fast it will take smaller amount. so should i take into account only the maximum serving time, when the cars are at their fastest velocity, or this example doesn't actually follow a poisson process.

Comment: There are usually safe minimum gaps between cars (distance? time? a function of speed?) so this cannot be a simple Poisson process.  What happens if there is congestion or if a faster car is behind a slower car?

Comment: But for an uncongested road with large gaps, it might not be a bad model.

Comment: it is often not congested